Integrating Newton's $2^{nd}$ law along path displacement in polar coordinates, handling separation of variables for second order differential terms
Suppose an object is moving on a frictionless dome (which consists in an upper half circle of radius $R$) from the top of the dome (at $\theta=0$) to a position $\theta =\theta_f$, in which it has acquired a velocity ($v_f$) upon the action of gravity.
The relationship between $v_f$ and $\theta_f$ can be found by applying $W_{nc} = \Delta E_{mech}$ ($W_{nc}$ is the work of the non-conservative forces). We take the gravitational potential to be $0$ at the center of the circle (or I'd rather say at the horizontal line passing through the center of the circle).
$$E_{mech,i}= mgR$$
$$E_{mech,f}= \frac{1}{2} m {v_f}^2 + mgR\cos(\theta_f)$$
Then applying $W_{nc} = \Delta E_{mech}$:
$$v_f = \sqrt{2gR(1-\cos(\theta_f))}$$
However, professor says we can get the same information by integrating tangential Newton's second law along the path of displacement.
I understand that the kinetic energy theorem ($W=\Delta K$) is a consequence of the integration of Newton's second law along the path of displacement; and that $W_{nc} = \Delta E_{mech}$ is a consequence of the kinetic energy theorem.
However, I can't find a way to derive the relationship between $v_f$ and $\theta_f$ from the integration of Newton's second law along the path of displacement in this particular polar coordinate system.
I know I should start with:
$$ mg\sin(\theta) = mR \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} \text{ (this is Newton's $2^{nd}$ law projected along the tangential unit vector)}$$
Then, integrating it along the path ($d\vec{s}=Rd\theta \hat{\theta}$) we get:
$$ g\sin(\theta) = R^2\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} d \theta$$
which must be integrated between $t=0$ and $t=t_f$ (or, if more convenient, from $\theta=0$ to $\theta= \theta_f$).
But I am facing difficulties in handling the separation of variables for "double" differential elements.

You have $$g \sin\theta = R \theta''.$$
Integrating both sides along the circular arc,
$$gR \int_0^{\theta_f} \sin\theta d\theta=
R^2 \int_0^{\theta_f} \theta'' d\theta,$$
where we recall that ' indicates derivative wrt time. Since a time derivative occurs on the RHS, we would like to change the integral to be over time, which we can do using $d\theta = \theta' dt$.
Thus,
$$gR (1-\cos\theta_f) =
R^2 \int_0^{t_f} \theta'' \theta' dt= R^2/2 (\theta'(t_f))^2 = v_f^2/2,$$
Which matches your result.
